# Paste Data into table without overwriting data VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, listobject, excel-tables

I am trying to filter data from one sheet and copy/paste that filtered data over into a summary sheet. I have 2 criteria that, if met, need to go into two separate summary tables. I am able to get the data filtered and copied, however, when it pastes into the respective tables, it is overwriting the total row at the bottom of the tables.

I need the data that is copied to go into the bottom of the tables, but above the last row so that the total rows are not affected.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterAndCopy()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim col As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("WH Locations")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Summary")

lngLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A31", "H" & lngLastRow)
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="C"
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=ws2.ListObjects("Table2")
    .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="D"
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy Destination:=ws2.ListObjects("Table3")
    .AutoFilter
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Copy SpecialCells to Excel Tables

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAndCopy()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("WH Locations")
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A31", "H" & slRow)
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    Dim sdcrg As Range: Set sdcrg = sdrg.Columns(1)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
    
    Dim srCount As Long
    Dim drCount As Long
    
    Dim dtbl2 As ListObject: Set dtbl2 = dws.ListObjects("Table2")
    If dtbl2.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then dtbl2.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    srg.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="C"
    
    On Error Resume Next
        srCount = sdcrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If srCount > 0 Then
        dtbl2.ShowTotals = False
        drCount = dtbl2.Range.Rows.Count
        dtbl2.Resize dtbl2.Range.Resize(drCount + srCount)
        sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dtbl2.Range.Rows(drCount + 1)
        dtbl2.ShowTotals = True
        srCount = 0
    End If
    
    Dim dtbl3 As ListObject: Set dtbl3 = dws.ListObjects("Table3")
    If dtbl3.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then dtbl3.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    srg.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="D"
    
    On Error Resume Next
        srCount = sdcrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If srCount > 0 Then
        dtbl3.ShowTotals = False
        drCount = dtbl3.Range.Rows.Count
        dtbl3.Resize dtbl3.Range.Resize(drCount + srCount)
        sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dtbl3.Range.Rows(drCount + 1)
        dtbl3.ShowTotals = True
        'srCount = 0
    End If
    
    sws.ShowAllData
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked great!  I added in totals for each column in the corresponding tables and it all works, thanks again.

Comment: Quick question, how would I make so that if I were to run the macro a second time only new entries would be pulled from the WH Locations sheet to the Summary Sheet?  Column A on WH Locations has a unique identifier that I could use to check and make sure that it isnt in wither table on the summary sheet.

Comment: In the source worksheet, add another column where you will flag each copied row with e.g. `Yes`. When filtering, use 2 filters e.g. `"C"` in one column (the operator set to `xlAnd`) and `"="` (blank) in this new column, and before copying, write `Yes` to it for all the visible cells. Try it yourself. If you get stuck, you can always ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to write a separate macro to handle copying  and pasting the data to a table.  In this way you can test your code independently of the main code.

If you just want to copy the values use `PasteSpecial`.

```
Sub PasteSpecialToNewRowsToTable(Table As ListObject, Source As Range, PasteType As XlPasteType)
    Rem Cancel the operation if the range contains no data
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Source) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim ShowTotals As Boolean
    
    With Table
        ShowTotals = .ShowTotals
        .ShowTotals = False
        Source.Copy
        .HeaderRowRange.Offset(.ListRows.Count + 1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial PasteType
        Table.ShowTotals = ShowTotals
    End With

End Sub
```

If you wanted to copy the values formulas and formats use `Range.Copy Detsination`.

```
Sub CopyRangeToNewListRow(Table As ListObject, Source As Range)
    Rem Cancel the operation if the range contains no data
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Source) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim ShowTotals As Boolean
    
    With Table
        ShowTotals = .ShowTotals
        .ShowTotals = False
        Source.Copy .ListRows.Add.Range
        Table.ShowTotals = ShowTotals
    End With
End Sub
```

### Usage

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Rem Paste Filtered Values to Table 2
    PasteSpecialToNewRowsToTable Table2, WHLocationsColumnHFilteredRange("C"), xlPasteValues
    
    Rem Copy Filtered Range to Table 3
    CopyRangeToNewListRow Table3, WHLocationsColumnHFilteredRange("D")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Public Property Get Table2() As ListObject
    Set Table2 = wsSummary.ListObjects("Table2")
End Property

Public Property Get Table3() As ListObject
    Set Table3 = wsWHLocations.ListObjects("Table3")
End Property

Public Function wsWHLocations() As Worksheet
    Set wsWHLocations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WH Locations")
End Function

Public Function wsSummary() As Worksheet
    Set wsWHLocations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
End Function

Public Function WHLocationsRange() As Range
    With wsWHLocations
        Set WHLocationsRange = .Range("A31", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    End With
End Function

Public Function WHLocationsColumnHFilteredRange(FilterValue As Variant) As Range
    With WHLocationsRange
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=FilterValue
        Set WHLocationsColumnHFilteredRange = .Cells.Offset(1)
    End With
End Function

Sub PasteSpecialToNewRowsToTable(Table As ListObject, Source As Range, PasteType As XlPasteType)
    Rem Cancel the operation if the range contains no data
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Source) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim ShowTotals As Boolean
        
    With Table
        ShowTotals = .ShowTotals
        .ShowTotals = False
        Source.Copy
        .HeaderRowRange.Offset(.ListRows.Count + 1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial PasteType
        Table.ShowTotals = ShowTotals
    End With
    
End Sub
    
Sub CopyRangeToNewListRow(Table As ListObject, Source As Range)
    Rem Cancel the operation if the range contains no data
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Source) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim ShowTotals As Boolean
        
    With Table
        ShowTotals = .ShowTotals
        .ShowTotals = False
        Source.Copy .ListRows.Add.Range
        Table.ShowTotals = ShowTotals
    End With
End Sub
```